# If reflection of light can move an object as Compton scattering can the same do light refraction?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, momentum, refraction

If reflection of light can move an object as Compton scattering can the same do light refraction? Should a miniature prism move due to refraction causing momentum exchange in the example on the picture?[image]

Comment: So your question is if there is momentum transferred to the prism, because photons leave the prism at another direction than the incoming direction, correct? Maybe this does help you <https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/300828/light-refraction-and-conservation-of-momentum>?

Comment: @CharlesTucker3 Thanks.